# complement of a complete bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I am a beginner at the topics, so I need some helps to understand.
For example $K_{1 ,7}$ is a complete bipartite graph.

1. Express the number of edges in $K_{1,7}^C$.
   I know that : $The~number ~of ~edges ~in ~a ~complete ~bipartite ~graph~ K_{p,q} = pq$ so $K_{1,7} = 7$
2. Is that $K_{1,7}^C$ connected or not?
   I know that the meaning of connected and I also know that if $K_{1 ,7}$ connceted then $K_{1,7}^C$ not conneted.
3. If $K_{1,7}^C$ not connected, how many connected component there? (I have no idea about this.)
4. what is the degree sequence $K_{1,7}^C$?
   I need some advise and explanation, that why I use $K_{1 ,7}$.
   My Solution (I could not draw it so I add image):
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: Do you know what the complement of a graph is? What is your best attempt at finding the complement of $K_{1,7}$?

Comment: @MishaLavrov  not really sure about it, Although in the book gives very little explanation for a simple graph.

Comment: What book are you using?

Comment: @MishaLavrov  Introductory Combinatorics by Richard A. Brualdi 3th Edition

Comment: To gain some intuition, try drawing out $K_{1,2}$, $K_{1,3}$, and $K_{1,4}$ and their compliments. You should see a pattern emerge.

Comment: @Bonnaduck  Thank u for the help

Comment: @Bonnaduck Is that right what I added??

Comment: Yes, its $21$. What's more important is that you know *why* its $21$. What is the number of edges of $K_{1,n}^c$ for any $n$?

Comment: @Bonnaduck  I've checked all of them , $K_{1,2}^c=1$, $K_{1,3}^c=3$, $K_{1,4}^c=6$, $K_{1,5}^c=10$ it seems $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}$

Comment: Close. Its $n(n-1)/2$. Notice that $K_{1,7}^c$ has two components. In the $7$-vertex component, every vertex is connected to every edge, so it's the complete graph on $7$ vertices, i.e. $K_7$. This is true for $K_{1,n}^c$ as well. The component with $n$ vertices is $K_n$, and in general, the number of edges on a complete graph with $n$ vertices is $n(n-1)/2$.

Comment: @Bonnaduck thank u, I understand.